# Apache WordUtils.capitalize not doing its job

Tags: java, string, apache-commons

I'm trying to capitalize the first character of a string. I've seen other articles on stack overflow, and tried the Apache common packages. However, the output stays lower case, and unmodified. Here's my code;

```
package name;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.Object;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

public class Name {


public static void main(String[] args){


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    String first = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    String last = input.nextLine();

    String full = (first + " " + last);

    WordUtils.capitalize(full);

    System.out.println("Your name is " + full);

    input.close();
    }

}
```

I've also tried

```
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    String first = input.nextLine();
            WordUtils.capitalize(first);

    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    String last = input.nextLine();
            WordUtils.capitalize(last);     

    System.out.println("Your name is " + first + last);
```

I tried using capitalzieFully, but that yielded no results either. (I'm aware of Object not being used, I just tried importing that as a test).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String is immutable in java.

```
 first= WordUtils.capitalize(first);
```

So you have re assign it to `first` that returned by the `capitalize` method.

```
    String first= "test";
    WordUtils.capitalize(first); 
   //Above method returns a new String,you are not receiving that

    // Still first is "test" because String is immutable.
     first= WordUtils.capitalize(first);  
    //Now  first  = "TEST"
```

And also do the same in remaining places.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation, I appreciate it. Keep up the good work man.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
last = WordUtils.capitalize(last);
```

The method returns a string, strings are immutable.

Comment: By this do you mean replace input.nextLine? Wouldn't that make me unable to enter my string?

Comment: it will assign next line to a variable last, and then change last to capitalized

Answer (score 1):

```
full = WordUtils.capitalize(full);
```

You need to assign the modified String back to itself for the changes to reflect. Because, strings are immutable.

Or if you don't wanna use any external library, you can do something like this:

```
full = Character.toUpperCase(full.charAt(0)) + full.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

without using any library

```
first=first.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+first.substring(1).toLowerCase();
last=last.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+last.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, you can modify your string at any time to something new later down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 WordUtils.capitalizeFully(full);
```